# MongoDB: Which Data Type for Date for faster search and performance - epoch/ISODate?

Tags: database, mongodb, date, mongoose, nosql

I have a use case where we need to search documents within the date range and performance is very important aspect.

I am under the impression that I will be able to search and fetch document comparatively faster using `epoch` timestamp by using number. I would definitely use **indexes** on date whenever needed.

Can someone experienced enlighten me on **benefits and drawbacks of `epoch`, `Date` and `ISODate`**. **mongosh** wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper, does it help in such case?

Comment: _"performance is very important"_  Seems that you should profile the different options for your application to see which option(s) work best.  You may also want to compare the sizes of the indexes generated.

Comment: @rickhg12hs keeping performance aside, would you be able help with understanding each of them?

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure what you mean by "epoch timestamp".  `Date` is stored as a millisecond offset from epoch.  Maybe you are considering storing just seconds offset?  You can find all the MongoDB BSON types [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/).